# DevExpress Integration to .Net Webapplication

Tags: asp.net, .net, devexpress

I am using DevExpress 6.2(a very old version) in my ASP>NET web application.with this version Devexpress the Grid Headers are not displayed in IE11. I am migrating Devpress 6.2 to latest DevExpress v17.2 and integrating it to my web application. But facing lot many issues while integrating it because many of the controls are obsolete in new version.

I need the substitute controls for these below mentioned controls from DE v6.2.

1. <%@ Register TagPrefix="dxwdc" Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxDataControls" Assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxDataControls.v6.3, Version=6.3.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=79868b8147b5eae4" %> 


   2.The Grid Controls

In brief, I need DE 17.1.3 version of below:

Aspxlookandfeelcontroller - Assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxDataControls.v6.3

Parent Control ASPxGrid - Assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGrid.v6.3 : This I believe should be replaced with ASPxGridView

Parent Control behavior – SearchBtnStyle

Parent Control behavior – GroupItemStyle

Child Controls within ASPxGrid – ButtonBars

ChildControl types for : BarButtons

Thanks,
Rama.

Answer (score 0):

From:[Devexpress update to latest version](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T228461)

> The best way is to install the latest version to the Development
>   environment. After that, use the [Project Converter](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#ProjectConverter/CustomDocument2529) tool to
>   convert your existing application to the latest version. Once it is
>   done, test your application locally to correct errors, if any. Once
>   your application works flawlessly in the Development Environment,
>   deploy it to your Production environment.

Upgrading ASP.NET Applications

1. Back up your project(s).
2. Upgrade your project(s) using the Project Converter tool.
3. Remove old DevExpress assemblies from the Bin folder (if any).
4. Build runtime licenses.

Refer these DevExpress Documenation and Support threads:
[How to easily convert your project to a new DevExpress release](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2007/09/10/how-to-easily-convert-your-project-to-a-new-devexpress-release.aspx)
[How to upgrade devexpress Project Version?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T197403)